# Xcode 4.1.1 constantly reindexing after a refactor 

Tags: performance, xcode4

Currently splitting an App into a (hopefully) reusable library for other games of the same franchise, and the game specifics, i do a 'lot' of refactoring. It seems that as i advance in this monk work, Xcode is creeping to a stall because it spends more and more time on reindexing the project after each refactoring action.

Any thoughts ?

MBP quadCore 2.3Ghz, 8GB, Lion, xCode 4.1.1

PS. I've had to step out of Xcode because of this, currently doing my refactoring with JetBrains' AppCode ... immature but promising product, but good enough for that work. Beats the pants out of Xcode on many code intensive usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i think this is what is happening (after comparing what AppCode does with Xcode). Xcode reindexes all files modified by the refactoring AND their dependancies, whilst AppCode only reindexes the affected files.  a bug in Xcode imho ...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your project index might be a little messed up. Have you tried deleting the project's Derived Data?

Open the Projects organizer window (Command-Shift-2, click the Projects tab). Select your project and click the Delete button next to the Derived Data path. Xcode will recreate the derived data (it'll index one more time and your next build will be a full build from scratch).

Comment: Thanks Joshua , still no luck. It indexes the 910 or so .h/.m files, running on all 4 at maximum speed for 30 seconds, every time it gets a chance. Frustrating, but i will keep looking.

Comment: earlier, i was in the throws of finishing the pre-release version, so i ignored xCode4 for a bit (previous updates of xCode had taught me to handle with care). What are you suggesting Joshua ??? Recreate a xCode4 native project from scratch ? 1820 files is bad enough, i cant really fathom the 2400 resources ...

Comment: hmmm ... and urghhh ... I now recall having turned off snapshots in june (xcode3) because it was exhibiting the same symptom , taking longer and longer. They may be related AND originate from the xCode3 project file.

Comment: I like that you're frantic about the merest suggestion of project stability, I cannot lie. :-) Unfortunately that was the direction I was headed. However, given the size of your project, it's possible it's just Xcode's problem handling a project that size. It may be a newer Xcode 4 might speed things up. Don't know, but a fresh new Xcode project would certainly answer a big question.